# What is the meaning of RabbitMQ Exchange from performance perspective

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker, node-amqplib

I have tried to find an answer but couldn't find anything solid.

Let's say i have system that split to 3 modules.(Just an example)

Users

Products

Orders

I can create 3 Exchanges, 1 for each module.(Assuming they are all the same type)
Or i can create 1 Exchange for everyone.

What will be the differences(Beside the logical separation between modules)

Are there any best practices related to performance in such case?

And another one.. There is any meaning of splitting channel in nodeJS?
Nodejs is single threaded but the I/O calls is working on the OS threads

Thanks for your help.. I would love to get clarification for that and if there is any official reference it will be great

EDIT: I am trying to achieve really good performance and low latency streaming which is cruical for my business.
I worked with rabbit before and i know him pretty(Worked in Java) well but when i started to read i wasn't sure what the exchange benefits? Why we need to create new exchange if we have the default(Performance wise) and if the channels have any meaning in nodejs application cluster where every node is single process

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the best design i can do to get good performance and latency.
I worked with rabbit before and someone created exchange to separate modules.I am trying to understand if there any other benefit if we create several exchanges..
The other thing is the channels.. I don't know if i need to create multiple channels or one is enough because nodejs is single threaded.

Comment: The best design is the one that does exactly what you need it to do but is also simple and easy to maintain. Multiple exchanges add needless complexity imho.

Comment: I agree in general but this doesn't answer the questions. 1.Multiple exchange have any performance impact? 2.Open channels in nodejs worth something? because nodejs is single threaded